# Set priority to an NSOperationQueue

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

GCD enables dispatching blocks to a queue according to 4 global priority queues (high, default, low, background).
I have several NSOperationQueues in my app but want to run each in different priority. As i understood NSOperationQueue is  an abstraction over GCD, and would like to set different priorities to the NSOperationQueue (similar to the GCD priority queues). Is there a way to do so? (found its possible to set a priority to an operation but not to the queue itself).

Answer (score 5):

Starting with iOS 8, the NSOperationQueue has a `qualityOfService` property, which does what I think the OP meant. From the [Class Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FNSOperationQueue_class%2Findex.html&ei=mHxfVJfKMITLaO-jgbgM&usg=AFQjCNEDhusw8t1CCzDhoyli9qEnkEUZ5A&sig2=A5YEpJdMQIA0ZTAPCrnDkQ&bvm=bv.79189006,d.d2s):

> This property specifies the service level applied to operation objects
>   added to the queue. If the operation object has an explicit service
>   level set, that value is used instead. [...]
>
> Service levels affect the priority with which operation objects are
>   given access to system resources such as CPU time, network resources,
>   disk resources, and so on. Operations with a higher quality of service
>   level are given greater priority over system resources so that they
>   may perform their task more quickly. You use service levels to ensure
>   that operations responding to explicit user requests are given
>   priority over less critical work.

Also in iOS 8, you can change which GCD queue is used with the `underlyingQueue` property, and therefore choose the global GCD queue with the desired priority.

Answer (score 1):

A quote from [NSOperationQueue Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html).

> Operations within the queue (but not yet executing) are themselves
>   organized according to priority levels and inter-operation object
>   dependencies and are executed accordingly.
>
> Inter-operation dependencies provide an absolute execution order for
>   operations, even if those operations are located in different
>   operation queues. An operation object is not considered ready to
>   execute until all of its dependent operations have finished executing.
>   For operations that are ready to execute, the operation queue **always
>   executes the one with the highest priority relative to the other ready
>   operations**.

Which means by design, you cannot set priority to a queue, but NSOperationQueue will use GCD global queue for individual operations depending on the operation's individual priority level.

Comment: no, NSOperationQueue only uses one GCD global queue, the default priority one. The NSOperation priority concept is unrelated.

Comment: I did not claim it uses GCD global queue with different priority levels. What I said and meant to say is that it executes tasks in order that depends on operation's individual priority level. @das

Comment: ok, your mention of 'GCD global queues' (plural) led me to that impression

Answer (score -2):

Try setting [`threadPriority`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) on the NSOperations that you add to the queue.

Comment: deprecated and only for OS X